# Gretty, setting "Module specified Libraries" from repository

Tags: java, jetty, gretty

I asked for similar question [jetty-jndi-resource-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042844/jetty-jndi-resource-fails-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-pool-o) using Jetty only, which is described by Jetty documentation as [Jetty: startup-classpath](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.19.v20190610/startup-classpath.html).

Now I like to use "Module specified Libraries" and setup it over Gretty as repository dependencies. I didn't find anything like this in Getty doc: [Gretty-configuration](https://gretty-gradle-plugin.github.io/gretty-doc/Gretty-configuration.html). I also search Gretty: [integratin-test](https://github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty/tree/master/integrationTests) Git for any usable example, but without result.

Is this Jetty feature unsupported over Gretty? Or is possible to setup the *--module=ext* parameter anyhow? Could anyone using *:farmRun* let me know how to handle the server provided external libs shared over multiple web applications in farm any clear way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "module specific libraries" that you are referring to are for the standalone version of Jetty.

If you see references to `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` concepts, and access to the `jetty-home` artifact (or the older `jetty-distribution` artifact) then you are working with a technology that uses the standalone version of Jetty.

Based on the Gretty documentation you have linked, it does not appear that Gretty uses the standalone version of Jetty, but rather the embedded-jetty (all in code) techniques to start Jetty.

The fact that Gretty has an optional XML startup feature means very little, as that XML is really just code to configure a object in their embedded-jetty setup, no different then having an interpreted script (in groovy or jsh) to accomplish the same thing.   There are no modules when using this Gretty setup.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. Please could you tell me what is the clear way to solve the provided libs (as e.g. ojdbc on WLS) which I do not like include in WAR in case of embedded-jetty used by Gretty. Actually I'm solving this by *grettyRunnerJetty* dependency type.